# SqlDeveloper blurry on high DPI Settings

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dpi, blurry, highdpi

I use a 4k monitor in the resolution 3840 x 2160 but with a scaling of 175% because at 100% everything is too small for me.
There are no problems with almost all applications and the writing is well readable due to the scaling.
Except the SqlDeveloper... all fonts seem to be blurred somehow. You can read them but somehow it is annoying.

I'm using Windows 11 by the way.

I've been through the google jungle myself and here's what I've tried:

- followed this guide: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/fixing-the-my-sql-developer-ui-is-so-tiny-problem/
- SqlDeveloper updated to 22.2.0
- downloaded jdk-17.0.4 and added it to product.conf `SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4`
- tried the same with jdk-18.0.2 (dont ask me why i thougth this will change anything...)
- sql developer => right click => properties => compatibility => override high dpi settings to Application

Google is full of solutions regarding the jdk and dpi settings but that's all I can find and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Changing the font size in SqlDeveloper is also not a solution for me because the size is already ok and that does not fix the blurriness.

So i hope there is someone out there who already fought that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution for this problem is to override the DPI settings of SQL Developer. To do this, open the properties of SQL Developer by doing a right click on the sqldeveloper.exe (or on a symbolic link pointing to it).

On the Compatibility tab, click an Change high DPI settings.

Now you are able to override the DPI scaling behavior. Change it from Application to System (Enhanced) and save the updated settings.

Source: https://christian-gohmann.de/2018/10/25/running-sql-developer-on-high-dpi-screens/

Answer (score -1):

Found your questions from google... At the end I gave up and just use DBeaver instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).